# MySQL - WHERE ATD is within minus 10 minutes from STD

Tags: mysql, sql, time

first post on Stack Overflow.
Been stuck on this issue for a few hours.

I want to find the entries where the "Actual Time of Departure" (ATD) is within minus 10 minutes from "Schedule Time of Departure" (STD). The two fields are of the TIME format ('14:04:30'). The last request I tried was:

```
WHERE `ATD` > `STD` - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE
```

but that doesn't work.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why doesn't your code work?  Can you provide sample data and desired results (in the *question* as text)?

Comment: `INTERVAL '10' MINUTE`?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer. Actually I just found the answer:

```
WHERE TIMEDIFF(`ATD`,`STD`) < '00:10:00'
```

Basically I wanted the request to list all the flights with an ATD which is less than 10 minutes before STD. For instance:

> flight 1 STD: 10:20:00  ATD: 10:16:00
>
> flight 2 STD: 14:50:00  ATD: 14:34:00

the first one would be listed, not the second one.

Sorry for being so basic in my explanation. I'll improve.